# Network adapter forgetting address?

Tags: networking

I started sysrescuecd v3.7.0 via USB on my PC because I'd like to backup my disk.
My idea was to use `dd` and `nc` to send data to a different PC, so I'm using `ip addr add` to configure the ethernet device like this:

```
ip addr add 192.168.212.11/24 dev enp0s25
```

and I can successfully ping the remote PC.

Problem is that, after a little while (some minutes), it seems that the OS is *forgetting* the configuration. Pinging doesn't work anymore and `ip addr show` displays an unconfigured network card. Of course, I'm not rebooting or issuing other `ip` commands in the meanwhile.

Anybody could help me figure out this, please?

Comment: What do the system logs have to say about this?

Comment: Don't you happen to have some sort of dhcp client running, that would mess with your network settings after it timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question: the culprit was the NetworkManager daemon who was messing with the interface configuration in the background, as @peterph correctly suggested.

To solve the situation I started the sysrescue's Xfce desktop environment and configured the network adapter via **Settings** | **Network Connection** GUI utility instead of `if addr` command.

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Can you please add more details? Did you prevent `NetworkManager` from managing your interface to circumvent this? I ask because I once faced a similar issue and thought it was `NetworkManager` but it seems the problem was with my wireless card driver.

Comment: @JosephR. hope it helps!

Comment: It's not the solution I expected but thanks :)